# Refresh element with ajax every one second my apache/browser becomes slow when running

Tags: jquery

I want to create refresh element every second using ajax, but i have problem my apache or browser becomes slow when running.
For example :

```
setInterval(function(){     
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        data: "start_dt="+start_dt+"&end_dt="+end_dt,
        url: base_url + url,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#log-status").html(data);
        },error: function(e) {
            //alert("Error cannot access url return [Log/Status]");
            $(".info-error-load").append("<p>Error cannot access url return [Log/Status "+e+"]</p>");
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Why my apache/browser become slow when running ?
Can anyone tells me how to fix it ?

Give me solution for this, please.

Comment: Try increasing 1000ms to a higher value.

Comment: server request happen every 1sec so request became pipe lined.

Comment: You are killing the server by sending a request every second. Increase the time delay or Server & Client RAM.

Comment: Do you have solution for me ?

Comment: websockets is a better way then making infinite POST requests.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket
Another way, 1 request per second is actually not that much. You should tweak the server to be able to respond under 100ms, either optimize your serverside script, or optimize the whole server.